# Optimal stopping under partially observable state

Tags: optimal-stopping

This problem is basically the classic asset selling problem but with imperfect state information.

In the classical problem, we have an asset that we wish to sell, we receive offers w(0) to w(N-1).  If we accept the offer at a given period, we can invest that money with a certain rate of interest r > 0.  We suppose that at period N-1, we will accept the offer if we haven't accepted any already.

In the problem I am trying to solve, the offers w(k) are independent and identically distributed.  However the common distribution of the w(k) is unknown.  Instead it is known that this distribution is one out of two given distributions F1 and F2, and that the a priori probability that F1 is the correct distribution is a given scalar q, with 0 < q < 1.

a)Formulate this as an imperfect state information problem and identify the state, control, system disturbance, observation, and observation disturbance.

b)Show that (x(k), q(k)), where

q(k) = P(distribution is F1 | w(0), ... , w(k-1))

is a suitable sufficient statistic, write a corresponding DP algorithm, and derive the form of the optimal selling policy.

The state would represent whether or not we have already sold our asset and if we haven't, the offer we have at this period.  The control would be to either accept or refuse the offer at this period.  The system disturbance would be the offer.  As for the rest of the question, I'm not too sure.